# which generates more efficiently, single or 3 phase systems

Tags: ac, battery-charging, generator, charging, tools

I want to build a hand crank generator for my travels and I am curious if there is an advantage to a three phase "motor used as generator" design or if it will be around the same output to a similarly rated ac motor or even a brushed dynamo.

I recently tried using a super potent rs775 with a nice long lever and high gearing ration of 1:160 but boy getting 20 watts (per hour rate) is hard, i could barely do 15 min. yet I saw this one small 25 watt generator review online with a lever half my size and was matching my output. I feel dumb almost, that they managed to do more with so much less. they had a small 3 phase generator with a much lower gearing.

So is this possible because of the 3 phase motor? or is this witch craft.

Comment: What are you intending to power with it?

Comment: you know just try to charge some lipo batteries or charging something like an ipad or laptop. Just things in the 20 watt range

Comment: If you have an AC generator you will need to convert it to DC somehow for that. Meaning loses.

Comment: yes I have all the wiering and stuff figured out because i looked at the schematics of the generators out there and already have all the components. my question lies in why that generator they used with the 3 phase could do the same electric output with a lot less effort in.

Comment: Phases don't matter, because any energy not turned into electricity just stays as kinetic energy in the flywheel.   Only losses in wiring resistance and magnetization matter.   Three phase motors are almost always soft iron, don't make good generators.   Permanent magnet DC motors do make good generators.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to build a hand crank generator for my travels and I am curious if there is an advantage to a three phase "motor used as generator" design or if it will be around the same output to a similarly rated ac motor or even a brushed dynamo.

A three-phase generator has an advantage over a single-phase one in that the load on the input - you in this case - remains even throughout the whole revolution. The single-phase will have high resistance when the sine output is maximum and low resistance near the zero-cross.

The DC brushed generator will be even as the brushes and communtator maintain the same relative position between the magnetic field and the excited winding.

> I recently tried using a super potent rs775 with a nice long lever and high gearing ration of 1:160 but boy getting 20 watts (per hour rate) is hard,

First we have no idea what a "super potent rs775" (sic) is. You should explain and provide a link to a datasheet.

Watts is not measured in "per hour rate". Instantaneous power is measured in watts (W). Energy is power by time and this is generally measured in watt-hours (Wh) or kWh.

You should be able to sustain 100 to 150 W power for hours when cycling or other work. 20 W seems about right for a hand-held generator. A two-hand crank arrangement similar to bicycle crank would probably allow a higher output as the arms can thrust against each other.

> i could barely do 15 min. yet I saw this one small 25 watt generator review online with a lever half my size and was matching my output. I feel dumb almost, that they managed to do more with so much less. they had a small 3 phase generator with a much lower gearing.
>
> So is this possible because of the 3 phase motor?

More likely due to measurement trickery. There will be some differences in efficiency but not much. With the lack of details in your question it is not possible to answer.

Comment: the rs motor i used is this one http://www.andymark.com/Motor-p/am-2194.htm I found the efficiency at 70% so i figured the rpms i needed to get to for a specific voltage, also figured this thing could handle a lot of amperage since during use it can handle 10 continuous amps. so I figured i could just pop a load on it with the tranny and a long lever and get the output.  but it resists me so much getting to the correct voltage is hard, and given i had a 20 watt load on, I measured the amp and it only read 2 amps. this other device does the same with 1/3 the effort.

Comment: given that electricity takes a certain amount to generate, I figured there would be efficiency differences out there but the difference between my system and this other one is just huge. which left me as to what is is that they measured so correctly that producing power for the is that much easier. or in other words makes my system so bad.

Comment: Is there any chance you can use standard English capitalisation and punctuation? It's hard work reading your comments.

Comment: You nead to measure *power*. You can calculate this from \$ P = VI \$ and compare the two systems. You also need to be aware that, as on a bicycle, maintaining the same output at different gear ratios will feel rather different.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information on that motor, but if it is not a Permanent Magnet DC motor, I suspect the lack of power output might be because you are not providing excitation to the brushes, so whatever it is generating is just the result of residual magnetism. Even if it is a PM DC motor, it appears to be rated for 44W (again, almost NO information on the motor itself), so your being able to sustain only 20W seems not too unreasonable. Power in = power out - losses. There are a lot of friction and heat losses in a gearbox. Average humans can sustain about 1/10HP continuously through their legs (i.e. bicycle), about 1/2 of that via arms only. 746W/HP means 75W via leg power, roughly 37W from your arms, and that is based on tests on college age healthy athletic types and military personnel getting regular training. Internet surfing slobs like me, probably half again... And I'll also agree that a lot of things you see demonstrated on internet videos are purposely deceitful for the purpose of separating fools and their money.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit of effort may be wasted by inefficiency of the mechanical gearing. There is an optimum operating speed for generator efficiency and an optimum cranking speed for hand cranking without getting too tired. Those two speeds must be matched by a combination of generator design and mechanical gearing. The minimum mechanical speed increase will provide the most efficient gear. The best quality gear will be the most efficient.

The most efficient generator will be a 3-phase, permanent magnet generator using the best available magnets, the best quality magnetic materials, the smallest possible air-gap and other design details that will make the generator more expensive.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible to simply use many poles and remove the gears all together? That way the energy wasted on the gears will disappear. Hmm, perhaps the number of poles required to replace the gears is an unrealistic number.

Comment: Yes. A sufficient number of poles to match the generator to the prime mover is the best approach. However reducing the speed requires the torque to increase for the same power. However, the cost of the generator is more directly proportional to torque than it is to power. Even so, the increased cost of the generator is often comparable to cost of the gear. For DIY generator projects, it may be very difficult to find motors with a lot of poles. The cost trade off doesn't seem to be there for tiny motors.

Answer (score 0):

Since conduction losses depend on \$ Pd=I^2R\$ and the generator only charges when the sine voltage exceeds the battery voltage, current will become pulses with single phase rectified. only when Vin > Vbat.

Thus for same average power, the peak current becomes inverse to the duty cycle and thus more lossy with the \$I^2\$factor.

For 3 phase generators, they use 6 diodes to reduce the ripple current significantly and thus be more efficient with lower peak currents for same power transfer and thus lower losses.

Motor/Generator type matters for power output and RPM to match your mechanical power.  Some offer 450W crank chargers with stationary bicycle attachments that takes 50% less effort and twice the power in 1/2 the time.  But expect these to cost 1~2$/W

p.s.  a 775 rupee generator ($15c) wont be very efficient.

Comment: What does the d stand for in your \$Pd = I^2R\$?

Comment: dissipated power from conduction losses in wire ( and some eddy current losses )